# puppeteer is sending error 500 on production in google app engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer

I have a code that getting a pdf out of a link with puppeteer functions , it works perfectly on local , once I uploading it to production it sending 500 error to client ..
hope someone could help

this is the code :

```
router.post('/getPdf', async (req,res)=>{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`https://meetee.io/export/${req.body.number}`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  const file = await page.pdf();
  let base64data = file.toString('base64');
  res.send({base64data})
})
```

the error I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:5
```

Comment: Edit your question and include error messages from Stackdriver.

Comment: @JohnHanley there is the error

Comment: you need to include more stack trace, as it's only way to find error

Comment: what you mean ? how I do it? @MedetTleukabiluly